# 3 hour calculation? ParallelMap & ParallelTable

Tags: parallelization, compile, code-review

I'm having some problems with slow Mathematica code... I'm basically doing a computation that's is expected to take 3 hours (!) in my Core i7 with 4 processors... I'm basically computing an index (of stock market options implied volatilities), with my data coming from a (359,835 x 17) matrix, which I call **CompleteMatrix**. However, I know that my code is too basic, and I'm trying to find some ways to improve it with **ParallelMap** / **ParallelTable** or even **Compile** (don't know how though). And, more interesting, for some calculations **Map** is faster than **ParallelMap** and **Table** is faster than **ParallelTable**... Here are some samples of my code and how long it takes to calculate:

```
PregaoMC[v_] := CompleteMatrix[[v, 1.]];
n = 359835;
```

(Is there any way to improve this function with Compile?!)

```
In[17]:= DeleteDuplicates[Table[PregaoMC[x], {x, 2., n}]];//AbsoluteTiming
Out[17]= {0.824105, Null}

In[18]:= DeleteDuplicates[ParallelTable[PregaoMC[x], {x, 2., n}]];//AbsoluteTiming
Out[18]= {1.080137, Null}

In[19]:= DeleteDuplicates[Map[PregaoMC, Range[2., n]]];//AbsoluteTiming
Out[19]= {0.707090, Null}

In[20]:= DeleteDuplicates[ParallelMap[PregaoMC, Range[2., n]]];//AbsoluteTiming
Out[20]= {1.022129, Null}
```

Another calculation which is taking a lot of time is:

```
AtivoMC[v_] := CompleteMatrix[[v, 2.]];

In[32]:= Select[Flatten[Position[{Table[AtivoMC[x], {x, 1, n}]}, "StockName"]], # > 1 &]; // AbsoluteTiming
Out[32]= {0.887112, Null}

In[33]:= Select[Flatten[Position[{Map[AtivoMC, Range[ 1., n]]}, "StockName"]], # > 1 &]; // AbsoluteTiming
Out[33]= {0.793101, Null}

In[34]:= Select[Flatten[Position[{ParallelTable[AtivoMC[x], {x, 1, n}]}, "StockName"]], # > 1 &]; // AbsoluteTiming
Out[34]= {1.150145, Null}

In[35]:= Select[Flatten[Position[{ParallelMap[AtivoMC, Range[ 1., n]]}, "StockName"]], # > 1 &]; // AbsoluteTiming
Out[35]= {1.040132, Null}
```

Apparently these calculations don't take too long, however I have to do them several times, for several different stocks and several different days... Is there any way to improve whis code with Compile?

Thank you!
Rodrigo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, I notice that you are using `Real` numbers such as `1.` and `2.` for [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) indexes.  While this works it would be better to use `Integer` indexes, `1` and `2`.

Your use of `PregaoMC` and then `Table`, etc., is highly inefficient.  `Part` and [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html) will be better.  Observe:

```
Table[PregaoMC[x], {x, 2, n}] === CompleteMatrix[[2 ;; n, 1]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
n = 359835;
CompleteMatrix = RandomReal[9, {n, 17}];

DeleteDuplicates @ CompleteMatrix[[2 ;; n, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.0250000, Null}
> ```

I believe your second code section is equivalent to this:

```
Join @@ Position[CompleteMatrix[[All, 2]], "StockName"]
```

This will likewise be much faster.

Comment: Fantastic! 7 times faster than previous code! Thank you!

Comment: @Rod Glad I could help.  You may wish to take a look at these posts: [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121), [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4721171/618728).

Comment: @Rod I got my links mixed up.  The first reference was supposed to be this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121

Comment: Great reference! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you again!!!